# How to echo php variable from array?

Tags: php, syntax, escaping

I need echo something like this:

```
echo "<a href="#">$some['variable']</a>
```

How can I escape `[]` brackets to echo variable in link?

Comment: What should your output look like?

Comment: Have you tried looking on the internet?

Comment: Need to escape your quotes first. It's terminating the string.

Comment: `echo "<a href='#'>".$some['variable']."</a>";`

Comment: you need to concatenate,no need for escaping anything

Comment: echo '<a href="#">'.$some['variable'].'</a>'; The best way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo "<a href='#'>" . $some['variable'] . "</a>";
```

or

```
echo "<a href=\"#\">" . $some['variable'] . "</a>";
```

or

```
echo "<a href='#'>{$some['variable']}</a>";
```

Comment: Thank you guys! Sorry for stupid question, a little bit tired.

Comment: Perfectly > "<a href='#'>{$some['variable']}</a>";

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
echo "<a href='#'>{$some['variable']}</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

- My favorite:

  ```
  echo "<a href='#'>$some[variable]</a>";
  ```
- **The only one that should ever be used**

  ```
  <a href="#"><?=$some['variable']?></a>
  ```

  or (preferred)

  ```
  <a href="#">{{ some.variable }}</a>
  ```

A note for the fellow experts: If you think that some of these codes are improper, consult documentation first.

Comment: Doesn't the second one require something to be enabled first?

Comment: @TomFenech nope it doesn't

Comment: Please dont encourage the usage of short tags.

Comment: @TomFenech I need to explain you one interesting thing. Beside Stack Overflow "experts" and ancient answers there are things like real life experience and up-to-date official documentation.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, PHP also allows for short open tags <? and ?> (**which are discouraged** because they are only available if enabled with short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option. _I highlighted something bold FYI._

Comment: @shankar: `<?=` is an exception though, because it is quite useful and doesn't have the same problem as `<?` when used with XML (I think).

Comment: I think that this discussion has shown that there is some confusion about the use of `<?=`, so perhaps it would be useful to [point to the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag), or at least state the minimum required PHP version (5.4.0) to use the tags in your answer.

Comment: @TomFenech the nature of this site doesn't encourage any quality improvements. Nobody wants to learn anything even if you provide them with links, explanations, lectures, books, encyclopedias, university courses. The only point of this site is getting rep points, not knowledge. I can fix this one particular answer, but thousands others will remain untouched. It's no use

Comment: @YourCommonSense I hope you are trying to be sarcastic; otherwise a defeatist attitude like that does not help someone like me who enjoys SO for it's more intelligent responses and who does not care about the rep points and coloured badges that appear by my name.

Comment: @Dave well, if this attitude doesn't help you - then find yourself one that suits you better. I am not sure I am getting you right though - why should my attitude help some random commenter and which way?

Comment: @YourCommonSense What I'm trying to say is that 'added value' responses: links, expl., etc that you say are useless are actually very helpful to anyone who wants to better their skills. Often this site has sent me to the most current info.; vs reading outdated answers elsewhere. If everyone on this site answered in minimalistic fashion, it would be no better than random results found googling. If you added a link to your answer showing why your answer is valid and possibly better than the accepted answer, I would feel inclined to +1 it in order to raise it to the top where it should belong.

Comment: @Dave look. First, this question is a duplicate. A bazillionth duplicate. Chances that google will choose this one out of that many are stall to none. Second, for some reason noone question other authors to add whatever links or explanations. So, it seems community is actually quite content with this kind of answers. I don't understand why mine attracted so much attention compared to others.

Comment: These comments are hilarious. **Short open tags are not the same as short echo tags**. Get it right! In PHP 5.4+, you can have short open tags off and still do `<?=`. This is a **short echo**. Get your facts straight. They look *much* better in your templates. I wish everyone would stop screaming about backward compatibility. No wonder PHP is struggling to go places.

Comment: `echo "<a href='#'>$some[variable]</a>";` — This could cause trouble if there's a constant named `variable`. Wrap it in curly braces to be safe: `echo "<a href='#'>{$some['variable']}</a>";`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 good ways to do it:

1. `echo '<a href="#">'.$some['variable'].'</a>';`
2. `echo "<a href=\"#\">$some['variable']</a>";`